# for on generic type error - class incompatibility

Tags: java

I've constructor class like this

```
public SelectOption(SysMyAbDao dao,Class<E> entity,String idName, String labelName ){

    this.dao = dao;
    this.entity = entity;
    entityAll = dao.findAll();
    try{
        Method idMethod = this.entity.getMethod(idName);
        Method labelMethod = this.entity.getMethod(labelName);
        for ( E single : entityAll) {
            optionList.put((String)idMethod.invoke(single),(String)labelMethod.invoke(single));
        }
    }catch (NoSuchMethodException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

but at this line

```
    E single : entityAll
```

i've got error:

Incompatible types.
Required: java.lang.Class 
Found:  E

But if I use

```
    Class<E> single : entityAll
```

I get

java.lang.ClassCastException: it.survey.model.AppQuestion cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

where it.survey.model.AppQuestion is E class that i pass to constructor

Comment: What's the type of `entityAll`?

Comment: It's ArrayList<E>